# Import-CSV: add rows (members) to resulting object in foreach loop

Tags: powershell, import-csv, psobject, pscustomobject

I am trying to achieve the following with imported CSV Data in Powershell:

the CSV has the following structure:

```
| FirstName | LastName | Tier |
| --------- | -------  | ---- |
|  George   | Smith    |  0   |
|  John     | Fritz    |  1   |
|  Thomas   | Adams    |  1   |
|  Manuel   | Evans    |  0   |
```

I import the CSV Data as follows:

```
$csv = Import-Csv csvfile.csv
```

Now here is the Problem. I am trying to add few more lines to the object

```
$csv
```

If a User is of Tier 0 then the same User should be added to the object with Tier 1.

The resulting $csv object should look like:

```
| FirstName | LastName | Tier |
| --------- | -------  | ---- |
|  George   | Smith    |  0   |
|  John     | Fritz    |  1   |
|  Thomas   | Adams    |  1   |
|  Manuel   | Evans    |  0   |
|  George   | Smith    |  1   |
|  Manuel   | Evans    |  1   |
```

The order in which the new Tier 1 rows are placed in the object do not matter. They should just be somewhere in the object with all the original data. I also do not need the resulting Tier 1 Lines in any CSV File. I only need those new Lines (Members) to be a part of $csv object with all other Data untouched so i can then iterate through original and new data in the same object using a foreach loop.

What i tried so far without positive results:

```
$csv = Import-Csv csvfile.csv

foreach ($User in $csv){ 
    $tier = $User.Tier -replace '\s',''
    if($tier -eq '0'){  
    $csv+= @{FirstName= $User.FirstName; LastName=$User.LastName; Tier='1'}
    }
}
```

another try without positive results:

```
$csv = Import-Csv csvfile.csv

foreach ($User in $csv){ 
    $tier = $User.Tier -replace '\s',''
    if($tier -eq '0'){  
        $csv | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'FirstName' -Value $User.FirstName -Force
        $csv | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'LastName' -Value $User.LastName -Force
        $csv | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Tier' -Value '1' -Force
    }
}
```

After failing miserably i have come to get help from the Wizards of StackOverflow.

How can i achieve this? How do i get the Tier 0 Rows duplicated with a different Tier Value while leaving all other Data untouched into the same object?

Comment: does the order in which new objects with Tier 1 are placed matter?

Comment: no, the order does not matter at all

Comment: Your last try is close.  What is wrong?

Comment: only the new lines appear in the object. the older original lines are gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way you can do it but note that this example does not check if `Tier 1` object already exists for a `Tier 0` object.

```
$newCsv = Import-Csv ... | ForEach-Object {
    $_
    if ($_.Tier -eq 0) {
        $copy = $_.PSObject.Copy()
        $copy.Tier = 1
        $copy
    }
}
```

Demo:

```bash
@'
FirstName|LastName|Tier
George|Smith|0
John|Fritz|1
Thomas|Adams|1
Manuel|Evans|0
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' | ForEach-Object {
    $_
    if ($_.Tier -eq 0) {
        $copy = $_.PSObject.Copy()
        $copy.Tier = 1
        $copy
    }
}

FirstName LastName Tier
--------- -------- ----
George    Smith    0
George    Smith    1
John      Fritz    1
Thomas    Adams    1
Manuel    Evans    0
Manuel    Evans    1
```

---

Your first attempt was very close, the problem is that you're adding a hashtable `@{ ... }` instead of a custom object `[pscustomobject]@{ ... }` to the `$Csv`, then it should work fine but you should also try to avoid `+=` as it is inefficient, you can do this instead which in the end is very similar to my example above:

```
$csv = Import-Csv ...
$newCsv = foreach ($User in $csv) {
    $User
    if ($User.Tier -eq '0') {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            FirstName = $User.FirstName
            LastName  = $User.LastName
            Tier      = '1' 
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to *add to* `$Csv` without producing a new array te recommendation is to use a `List<T>` and its `.Add` method. This method also requires a `for` loop instead of `foreach` otherwise you would get an error due to trying to mutate a collection while being enumerated.

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] $csv = Import-Csv ...
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $csv.Count; $i++) {
    if ($csv[$i].Tier -eq '0') {
        $csv.Add([pscustomobject]@{
            FirstName = $User.FirstName
            LastName  = $User.LastName
            Tier      = '1' 
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case @Zombievirus instead of `+=` the recommendation would be to use a `List<T>` and its `.Add` method (see update)

Comment: thank you santiago. i will try. i am trying to do it all in one loop. import the csv then start the loop to do the required changes to the users and if a tier 0 user is found then add tier 1 user with same info to the object which is already being used in the foreach loop i currently am in hoping that the same loop will find the added users on the next iteration

Comment: unfortunately getting an error. Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. i guess it won't work without an additional array

Comment: @Zombievirus that update should fix the enumeration error but it's only adding more complexity to a simple problem. You should use the examples 1 or 2

Comment: the first example returned an array of original data + original data + corrected tier 1 duplicates. an original tier 0 user appeared in the array 3 times (twice with original data and once with correction of tier) and a tier 1 user appeared twice. correction was to delete the $_ in the beginning of foreach loop

Comment: @Zombievirus idk what you mean. im using the sample data you've provided and it is working fine, even added a reproducible example to the answer.

Comment: now i know what i did wrong. $csv = Import.. in first line and then $csv | Foreach.. from second line on. This is why the output was different. now it's all fixed and working perfectly. thank you Santiago. I upvoted your answer. The First Example is indeed the best solution.

Comment: @Zombievirus glad it helped. possibly it was failing before for you because your rows might have white spaces on each cell? Like I see you're doing `-replace '\s',''` so that might be the reason why it was failing? Also, I recommend you to do `$user.Tier.Trim()` to remove white spaces if thats the case